# Toggling between NRSE, RSE and Differential Analog inputs in LabWindows CVI

Tags: nidaqmx, labwindows, cvi, daq-mx

I'm having some issues reading analog input from a DAQ card in LabWindows CVI; the input configuration seems to be set to "Differential" by default, and I was wondering how I would go about changing that to NRSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `DAQmxCreateAIVoltageChan()`, use [`DAQmx_Val_NRSE`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370471W-01/daqmxcfunc/daqmxcreateaivoltagechan/) instead of `DAQmx_Val_Cfg_Default` for the `terminalConfig` parameter.